# Twitter login not showing screen in Parse.com Android?

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I create Parse.com application and create Twitter Application as well. I updated Consumer and Consumer Secret key in Parse application.

I wrote following code:

onCreate() of Application:

```
Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_KEY_PARSE, CLIENT_KEY_PARSE);
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("Consumer_key", "consumer_secret_key");
```

This my code on Twitter Button login:

```
twitterLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(MainActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp",
                                    "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            Log.d("MyApp",
                                    "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

But when i click button it shows loading but doesnt Twitter login. Please help.

Comment: Do you get any of the log messages from your onClick method in your log cat?

Comment: Try changing the MainActivity.this, to just this in your ParseTwitterUtils.logIn method and let me know the outcome as well please

Comment: 01-29 17:58:59.609: W/DefaultRequestDirector(2928): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=www-authenticate: OAuth realm="https://api.twitter.com"}

Comment: get above error and when i click again:

01-29 17:59:32.706: E/AndroidHttpClient(2928): Leak found
01-29 17:59:32.706: E/AndroidHttpClient(2928): java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed
01-29 17:59:32.706: E/AndroidHttpClient(2928):  at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.<init>(AndroidHttpClient.java:158)
01-29 17:59:32.706: E/AndroidHttpClient(2928):  at android.net.

Comment: your first error would suggest you have a problem with authenticating with twitter, rather than a Parse.com problem. I would suggest taking a look here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation to see if you are doing anything wrong and also check your twitter account is setup correctly

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing settings in Twitter application page as follows:

By specifying http://www.localhost.com/callback for Callback URL and http://www.localhost.com for a website in the Twitter application settings.

I dont know but this solved it.